# Javascript code to Checkall the checkboxes in DataGrid is working fine in IE but not working in chrome and FireFox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Code is working fine in IE and on click of checkbox all other checkboxes in DataGrid is checking but while working with Chrome and FireFox its not working

This is my code in Asp.net:

```
<HeaderTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkAllDetach" AutoPostBack="false" 
    onclick="SelectAllCheckboxes(this,'dgDetach',11);">
  </asp:CheckBox>
 </HeaderTemplate>
```

Javascript function:

```
function SelectAllCheckboxes(spanChk,dgGrid,intRow)
{

    var strRows = document.getElementById(dgGrid).rows;                                                             
    try
    {
        for(i=1;i<strRows.length;i++)
        {                       
            strRows[i].cells[intRow].childNodes.item(0).checked = document.getElementById(spanChk.id).checked;
            HighlightRow(strRows[i].cells[intRow].childNodes.item(0));
        }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        var r = '';
        for (var p in e)
            r += p + ': ' + e[p] + '\n';
        alert(r);
        return false;
    }
}

function HighlightRow(chkB)  
{
    if(chkB.checked == true)
    {
        chkB.parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor='#BFE3F6';        
        //chkB.parentElement.parentElement.style.color='';        
    }
    else
    {
        chkB.parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor='';        
        //chkB.parentElement.parentElement.style.color='#BFE3F6';        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Id element must by unique in DOM elements.
Try to set name="dgGrid" on your Html elements and then call them in your function like:

```
var strRows = document.getElementsByName("dgGrid");
```

Comment: What makes you think IDs are a problem here and how would your suggestion help anything?

Comment: Thanks for the reply I'm using same code in different pages and every time sending unique DOM elements.